# EPPlus Open File and lock file through multiple saves

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to be able to open an Excel file (or create if it doesn't exist) and add data to it asynchronously. I have the async component working quite well using a blocking collection, though if I want to save every loop of my while statement i keep getting issues.
I can either get file corruption, or the data never saves at all. Or sometimes it only saves the first or second data segment in my two part test.

I have the following code to show a similar cut down version of my issue:

```
BlockingCollection<Excel_Data> collection = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(fs);
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    //---- do some asyc operations
    Excel_Data dict_item = collection.Take();
    excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet" + i.ToString());
    //excel.Save();
    excel.SaveAs(fs);

    if (++i == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
fs.Close();
```

In the above example after simply create 2 sheets, the file already becomes corrupted and I am unsure how to fix this issue without going purely with FileInfo over FileStream. But then i will never be able to lock my file for writing for the duration of my app.

Comment: Why save the excel inside the while loop and not outside?

Comment: The function is used to handle adding data to a file for the duration of the application. It could last a few seconds or hours. The while loops should stay active for the whole app. During that time I wanted the data to be used externally when simply "reading" the file, so it keeps a live status of the file at all times.